# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

When I run this Java code:

```
public void run(){
    String stringPacketData=null;
    try {
        stringPacketData = new String(clientPacketData,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }       
    String[] splitString=stringPacketData.split("@");
    this.clientID = Integer.parseInt(splitString[0]);
    String op="";

    op=splitString[1];
    if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("popola_cache")){
        popolamentoCache(Integer.parseInt(splitString[2]));
    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Where stringPacketData has a format: idClient@operationType@dimCache, it will throw this excpetion:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at UDPSocketBased.WorkerUDP.run(WorkerUDP.java:53)
```

WorkerUDP.java:53 statement corresponds to:
    popolamentoCache(Integer.parseInt(splitString[2]));

I can't understand why my input string "5" is not in the correct format.

Comment: Print the number and check what is displayed. `5` or something along with `5`

Comment: Is it possible that parsed string contains some unprintable characters? Can you print all code-points of all its characters like `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourString.chars().toArray()))` (assuming that you have access to Java 8.

Comment: Have you checked the length of the string you are parsing? A non-printing character might cause the exception without being visible in the message.

Comment: Can you print the "clientPacketData" and post the result?

Comment: I think `splitString[2]`  contains  End of String '\n' try to 

    splitString[2].replace("\n","" ).replace("\r","" )

Answer (score 0):

First you need to trim your string before trying to parse it

```
this.clientID = Integer.parseInt(splitString[0].trim());
```

Comment: This is good approach but trim doesn't remove some special characters

Comment: a trim is an example , you can use regular expression to extract numbers between @ caracters and I think it's better in that case

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it in this way:

```
popolamentoCache(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(splitString[2].charAt(0))));
```

The problem was that I received a DatagramPacket called "pkt":

```
byte[] buffer=new byte[65508];
DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
```

So, when I get my packet data with:

```
clientPacketData=pkt.getData();
```

it considers a payload length of 65508 byte, in the same way stringPacketData length.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try put one delimiter character, the same that you use to split the string at the beginning of yours text file. This way you avoid the situation when first character throws the exception because that's not a integer.